# How do I add javascript autocomplete to markdown mode of monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I want to be able to use the javascript-autocomplete of the monaco editor inside of markdown documents as well, because markdown documents can contain code snippets of type javascript:

````
```javascript
window.blah
```
````

I know that I could register a custom CompletionItemProvider for markdown, but I want to use the javascript one already provided by monaco. I have not found a way to receive their provider however.

Javascript *syntax highlighting* already works in markdown code blocks.

My idea was to somehow get their provider using something like this:

```js
(await monaco.languages.typescript.getJavaScriptWorker()).something
```

For that to work I'd have to register javascript on the editor however. Even if I do that, I don't seem to be able to find anything on their worker that could help me.

While there's a method to register a CompletionItemProvider (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registercompletionitemprovider), I couldn't find any that could help me get a registered provider.

How can I use the javascript-autocomplete in markdown code blocks as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Here's how I use typescript/javascript worker APIs to provide their completions in a mixed language environment:

```js
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    const workerPromise = (context.language === "javascript")
                        ? languages.typescript.getJavaScriptWorker()
                        : languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker();
                    void workerPromise.then((worker: (...uris: Uri[]) => Promise<TypescriptWorker>) => {
                        void worker(model.uri).then((service) => {
                            const offset = model.getOffsetAt(localPosition);
                            const promise = service.getCompletionsAtPosition(model.uri.toString(), offset);

                            void promise.then((completions: CompletionInfo | undefined) => {
                                if (completions) {
                                    const info = model.getWordUntilPosition(localPosition);
                                    const replaceRange: IRange = {
                                        startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                                        startColumn: info.startColumn,
                                        endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                                        endColumn: info.endColumn,
                                    };

                                    resolve({
                                        incomplete: false,
                                        suggestions: completions.entries.map((entry) => ({
                                            label: entry.name,
                                            kind: this.convertKind(entry.kind),
                                            range: replaceRange,
                                            insertText: entry.insertText || entry.name,
                                        } as CompletionItem)),
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    resolve({ incomplete: false, suggestions: [] });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Important here is that you create submodels with only the content of the parts in a single language (see `Monaco.createModel()`) and use that to invoke the completion items code.

In my app I split the content of an editor into blocks (each covering only full lines and which have a specific language attached to them). So they have a start line and an end line. With this information I can create sub models for each block:

```js
    /**
     * @returns A local model which contains only the text of this block. The caller must dispose of it!
     */
    public get model(): Monaco.ITextModel {
        const editorModel = super.model; // Model for the entire editor content.

        if (!this.internalModel || this.internalModel.isDisposed()) {
            const localModel = Monaco.createModel("", this.language);
            // Do other required preparations of the local model, if needed.
            this.internalModel = localModel;
        }

        if (editorModel && this.modelNeedsUpdate) {
            this.modelNeedsUpdate = false;
            this.internalModel.setValue(editorModel.getValueInRange(
                {
                    startLineNumber: this.startLine,
                    startColumn: 1,
                    endLineNumber: this.endLine,
                    endColumn: editorModel.getLineMaxColumn(this.endLine),
                }, Monaco.EndOfLinePreference.LF),
            );
        }

        return this.internalModel;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I don't really understand is how to invoke this code. I currently have one model per file, how do I use these submodels you suggested? Can you show a short code-snippet to get me started with these submodels?

Comment: I updated my answer with code to create sub models.

Comment: Okay, that's somewhat clear now, but what do I do with those submodels then? Can the monaco editor hold multiple models? How do I put those submodels together into one editor?

Comment: You use the sub models only for the language service APIs. The editor still has its own overall (full) model. You have to keep submodels in an own structure where you keep track of the sub areas in your main document.